# Make JTable Display only added Row

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

Right now I have a JTable using an AbstractTableModel that is using JDBC to access a SQL database. I do this

```
stmt.executeUpdate(someStr);
fireTableRowsInserted(rowCount,rowCount+1);
```

This obviously adds the row on the JTable. However, what I'd like to happen is for the JTable to show only the added row.

I thought of maybe creating a result set that contained only the added row, but I can't get that because I don't have an incremental id field.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: *This obviously adds the row on the JTable* ... euh, no

Comment: You might create a temporary table model consisting only of the newly added row and set it to table.

Comment: <teeth gritting> do-not-fire-events-on-behalf-of-the-model.Period. Instead implement the model to fire as appropriate. BTW: the interval is inclusive the boundaries. As to you requirement (sounds a bit strange to me, but ..): remove all rows except the newly added.

Comment: @kleopatra, you mean make a custom event for the model to fire?

Comment: no, that's not what I wrote :-)

Comment: wait, but if I'm firing that event inside of a method in the model, then isn't the model firing the event? Also, how do I identify the newly added - if I'm adding one at a time, just by looking at the index of the last row?

Comment: okay, then I jumped to conclusions :-) You need some logic, obviously (compare the keys or something, don't know). Anyway, _why_ do you want it?

Comment: because someone wants me to do it and I hate it and it's stupid and it makes more sense for me to just add it because that's what JTable wants to do

Comment: Could you just highlight the newly added row instead?

Comment: You could use a Table filter, the problem is going to be identifying the new rows. This would allow you to turn the filtering on and off

Answer (score 1):

1. don't reinvent the wheel, search for `ResultsetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase` (all event are dome on `EDT` and `Swing GUI` waiting / freeze untill all events ended, based on `AbstractTableModel`)
2. reinvent the wheel,

   a) use `Runnable#Thread()` or `SwingWorker` (`publish()`, `progress()`) for `JDBC`

   b) create a proper `AbstractTableModel`, there are to override proper notifiers,

   c) use the notifiers in the Model, `"fireTableRowsInserted(rowCount,rowCount+1);"`

   d) all updates to the `Swing GUI`, `JTable`, `XxxTableModel` must be done on `EDT`
3. if there are requirents about strictly to override the methods in `AbstractTableModel`, then look for correct `AbstractTableModel`, otherwise to use `DefaultTableModel` and call from `Runnable#Thread()` or `SwingWorker` only `myModel.addRow()`, nothing else
4. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with data hardcoded into `Array` instread of `JDBC Connections`